# Comparable Java Ordering

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestPerson{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        person Albert = new Person(1);
        person James = new Person(2);
        person Elizabeth = new Person(3);
        person [] personArray = new Person[3];
        personArray[0] = Albert;
        personArray[1] = James;
        personArray[2] = Elizabeth;
        Arrays.sort(personArray);
        System.out.println(personArray[0].number);
        System.out.println(personArray[1].number);
        System.out.println(personArray[2].number);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Person implements Comparable{
    int number;
    public Person(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }
    public int compareTo(Object o){
        if(!(o instanceof person)){
            System.out.println("error");
            System.exit(1);
            person newObject = (person) o;
            if (this.number > newObject.number){
                return 1;
            }
            else if(this.number == newObject.number){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I'm confused as to why the output is sorted backwards: 3,2,1. My compareTo method returns a positive number when this.number>number, so shouldn't that ensure that the numbers are sorted in order -- from smallest to greatest?
Thanks

Comment: If I read outermost `if` statement in your `compareTo` correctly, looks like the method will always return -1...

Comment: Protip - `Comparable<Person>` will work a lot better than `Comparable` here

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your `compareTo` method which always returns -1. However you can simplify your `compareTo` method quite a bit by implementing `Comparable<Person>` rather than `Comparable`:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        return this.number - other.number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You only need to change your `compareTo` method to the following, so it can return an error in case the passed is not an instance of `person`, otherwise it will cast the passed object and compare it:

```
 public int compareTo(Object o){
    if(!(o instanceof person)){
        System.out.println("error");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    person newObject = (person) o;
    if (this.number > newObject.number){
       return 1;
    }
    else if(this.number == newObject.number){
       return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: So what does the -1 and 1 effectively mean. How do I go about sorting things the way that I want.

Comment: As the documentation says: `a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.`  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html